# Найти в дереве длину (число ветвей) пути от корня до ближайшей вершины с элементом n.

Tags: prolog

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как найти в дереве число ветвей от корня до заданной вершины.

Используемое дерево:

```
                 ( 3 )
                /     \
               /       \
            ( 2 )      ( 5 )
            /   \          \
           /     \          \
        ( 1 )   ( 2 )      ( 8 )
                           /
                          /
                        ( 9 )
```

Код рекурсивного прохода по дереву:

```
    domains
    treetype = tree(integer, treetype, treetype); empty()
predicates
    traverse(treetype)
clauses
    traverse(empty).
    traverse(tree(Name, Left, Right)) :-

        write(Name,'\n'),
        traverse(Left),
        traverse(Right).

goal
    traverse(tree(3,
        tree(2,
            tree(1, empty, empty),
            tree(2, empty, empty)),
        tree(5,
            empty,
            tree(8, 
                tree(9, empty, empty), 
                empty)))).
```

Нужно как-то дописать код, чтобы он мог посчитать кол-во ветвей. Например между точкой 3 и 9 результат должен вывестись 3. Между 3 и 8  в результате должно отобразиться 2.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А какая версия пролога?

Comment: Программирую на Visual Prolog 5.2.

Comment: Вроде в турбо прологе работает, посмотрю что можно сделать.

Comment: Спасибо большое :) Можно и в турбо прологе. Установлю если что его :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде работает. В branch первым параметром пишем искомое число, вторым - дерево. Если число найдено, выводит длину пути до него от корня. Если не найдено, пишет число такое-то not found. Делал в turbo prolog, но по идее должно работать и в visual prolog.

```
domains
    treetype = tree(integer, treetype, treetype); empty()
predicates
    traverse(treetype)
    nondeterm br(integer,integer,treetype)
    nondeterm branch(integer,treetype)
clauses
    traverse(empty).
    traverse(tree(Name, Left, Right)):-
        write(Name,'\n'),
        traverse(Left),
        traverse(Right).
    br(_,_,empty):-fail.
    br(X,Y,tree(X,Left,Right)):-write(Y).
    br(X,Y,tree(_,Left,Right)):-Y1=Y+1, br(X,Y1,Left).
    br(X,Y,tree(_,Left,Right)):-Y1=Y+1, br(X,Y1,Right).
    branch(X,Tree):-br(X,0,Tree);write(X," not found\n").
goal
    branch(8,tree(3,
        tree(2,
            tree(1,empty,empty),
            tree(2,empty,empty)),
        tree(5,
        empty,
        tree(8,
            tree(9,empty,empty),
            empty)))).
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное :)
Выводится две ошибки, но они легко исправляются.
Для этого нужно:

В predicates заменить следующие строчки:

br(integer,integer,treetype)
branch(integer,treetype)

на такие:

nondeterm br(integer,integer,treetype)
nondeterm branch(integer,treetype)

Comment: Исправил. А что nondeterm значит кстати? и что за ошибки были?

Comment: в Турбо Прологе все предикаты nondeterm, т.е. в них работает бэктрекинг. А в Visual Prolog в предикатах по умолчанию бэктрекинг не работает. По моему скромному мнению, это нарушает чистоту идеи

Comment: Ага, понятно. Просто ни с Turbo, ни с Visual раньше не сталкивался.